# Won't ask for password after sleep on Sonoma

Tags: sleep-wake, apple-silicon, sonoma

If I wake up the MacBook shortly after putting it to sleep it doesn't ask for the password.
I want it to ask for the password regardless of whether I had put it to sleep explicitly, or it had gone to sleep after a period of inactivity.

I'm using the MacBook in clamshell mode, in case that matters.